# django localflavor for international site

Tags: django, django-localflavor

Looks like the general usage of localflavor is import the country specific package:

`from localflavor.nz.forms import NZRegionSelect`

What if I have a site that supports multiple countries? Is there generic proxy to be country agnostic, something like:

`from localflavor.autodetect.forms import RegionSelect`

Comment: One option would be to import based on some criteria - such as  settings..

Comment: @karthikr that's right, I was thinking about that, but at this stage we are not sure if we have location based web servers yet.

Answer (score 3):

**__import__** would do the trick:

```
def get_region_select(country_code):
    module_path = 'django.contrib.localflavor.{}'.format(country_code)
    try:
        module = __import__(module_path, fromlist=['forms'])
    except ImportError:
        return None

    fieldname = '{}RegionSelect'.format(country_code.upper())
    if hasattr(module.forms, fieldname):
        return getattr(module.forms, fieldname)()
    return None
```

Adapted from: http://codeinthehole.com/writing/validating-international-postcodes-in-django/

Then, in your template you'll have to reload the page each time you change the country, and do something like this in the view:

```
form.fields['region'].widget = get_region_select(country)
```

Since different regions will have different choices.